# iOS keyboard extension paste video files to third party apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios-keyboard-extension

I have been working on an iOS keyboard extension that sends video files through iMessages.

This functionality works fine with copy + paste methods but when trying to copy + paste into a third party app (IE: Facebook, WhatsApp, Line etc) the "paste" option does not show up.

Is there some way I can get these files to be pasted into these apps? Or is this not possible on iOS?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: How are you loading the videos and copying it into the pasteboard? Can I have the sample code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Different Apps have different behaviors that are allowed in their textfields, as specified by the developers of those Apps. You can't force them to accept content that they don't want to.

Generally, most popular Apps with text input either support copy-pasting images directly, or will automatically download and display the contents of links that the user copy pastes.

You should check out Riffsy, the last time I used their GIF Keyboard App they had a feature where if you long pressed on a GIF, a list of social media apps appeared, and selecting one of them performed the appropriate action to display an image in text fields in that App.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy + paste any image, GIF or any video file that was loaded in your custom keyboard into any other app(i.e third party apps) other than the iMessage, That app input view(i.e text fields or text views) must support the images etc. If they don't support the images or videos you can't paste it in that input view.